# Error If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module

Tags: angular

I get this error when i try to enable lazy loading.
Currently i have  in all the components which shows the footer.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-footer' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-footer' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-footer' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    [ERROR ->]<app-footer></app-footer>
  </section>
  <section class="body-right-insidepages  animated fadeInRig"): ng:///OurPoliciesModule/OurPoliciesComponent.html@276:4
```

Currently i am implementing this in our-policies component which also had  at the end of the page. Both our-policies module and our-policies routing are inside the component directory of our policies.

Our policies routing

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { OurPoliciesComponent } from './our-policies.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "", component: OurPoliciesComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OurPoliciesRoutingModule { }
```

our policies module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { OurPoliciesRoutingModule } from './our-policies-routing.module';
import { OurPoliciesComponent } from './our-policies.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [OurPoliciesComponent],
      exports: [OurPoliciesComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        OurPoliciesRoutingModule
      ]
    })
    export class OurPoliciesModule { }
```

In the app.module

```
 imports: [ 
 OurPoliciesModule
 ]
```

If I remove `OurPoliciesModule` from app module `imports` and remove `exports: [OurPoliciesComponent]` inside our-policy module then the error only shows up when i go to localhot:4200/our-policies route and not in other components. And after that if I remove app-footer from our policies then the page loads without any error

Comment: This has nothing to do with your `OurPolicies` component or module. In which components's template are you using `app-footer` component? where did you declared it?

Comment: i created app-footer using cli before i tried lazy loading. So FooterComponent is already in declarations of app module

Comment: app-footer is being used inside our-policies and all other componets as footer.

Comment: I think this is the issue but dont know what do do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49587873/lazy-loading-component-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a shared module declaring your `app-footer` component, that all app modules can import and use your `app-footer` component using it.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-lazy-loading-module-reproduce-error) **reproducing** your issue.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nbs-angular-lazy-loading-module-fix-error) **fixing** the issue.

Follow this steps:

1. Create a `SharedModule` with declaration of your `app-footer` component.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppFooter } from '../components/app-footer.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppFooter ],
  exports: [ AppFooter ]
})
export class SharedModule {
}
```

2. Remove the declaration of `app-footer` from `AppModule`.
3. Import `SharedModule` in your `AppModule` and in `OurPoliciesModule`.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedModule } from '../shared-module/shared.module'; // or some other path to it
import { OurPoliciesRoutingModule } from './our-policies-routing.module';
import { OurPoliciesComponent } from './our-policies.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [OurPoliciesComponent],
      exports: [OurPoliciesComponent],
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        OurPoliciesRoutingModule,
        SharedModule
      ]
    })
    export class OurPoliciesModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the app-footer component to the declarations array of the app.module.ts

```
  declarations: [AppFooterComponent],
```

Comment: i created app-footer using cli before i tried lazy loading. So FooterComponent is already in declarations of app module